# Unable to update 2D Vector element value using their index location

Tags: vector, multidimensional-array, graph, std, adjacency-matrix

```
vector<vector<int>> arr{
    {1,2},
    {2,3},
    {4,5},
    {1,5}
    
};
vector<vector<int>> adj( m , vector<int> (m, 0));
```

for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {

```
    // Find X and Y of Edges 
    int x = arr[i][0]; 
    int y = arr[i][1]; 

    // Update value to 1 
    adj[x][y] = 1; 
    adj[y][x] = 1; 
}
```

I am trying to update the vector of vector value using the above code but I am getting a segmentation error. How can I change the element value of the 2D vector of a particular location.

Comment: What is "m"?  Remember that C++ arrays start counting at zero,.  If m is 5, then your "adj" array is too small; the indices will run from 0 to 4.

Comment: m is just a random number like int m = 5.

Comment: "m" can't be a random number.  "m" has to be large enough that all of your points fit in the `adj`.  With the data you have in `arr`, "m" must be at least 6.  Otherwise, you're exceeding the bounds of `adj`, which causes a segmentation fault.